# open the mail on outlook using mailto encode problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi In my webpage I generate the information and using mailto for opening the mail on outlook for the user modify the email. It worked fine. However when  the body or subject has apostrophe that cause problem, so I used Server.UrlEncode to encode the string. Now, the space show '+' and the new line show '\n'. If I don't use Server.UrlEncode, the function is not called.

There is my code to call the javascript function in vb.net

```
Dim strSubject As String = Server.UrlEncode(strName)
Dim strBody As String = Server.UrlEncode("it's your order list:" & "\r\n" & strList)
Dim script As String = "MailtoOrder(''," & "'" & strSubject & "', '" & strBody & "')"
If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "mail") Then
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "mail", script, True)
End If
```

There is my javascript:

```
function MailtoOrder( to, subject, body) {
   var email='';
   if (to != undefined) {
    email=to;
   }
    email = email + '&subject=' + encodeURIComponent(subject) + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(body);  

    window.location.href = "mailto:" +   email;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get away using Server.UrlEncode. I just replace the apostrophe  to be escaped character in  strSubject and strBody string. it works.